# Wordpress php read database in if statement

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I just installed the plugin: insert PHP.
With this plugin I am able to use php code in my pages.

I am not very familiar with php and can't find out how to read data from my wp_users table.

I have a column called weeks in my wp_users table.
I would like to do an if statement like this:

```
if ( wp_users_weeks('1') ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
```

but wp_users_weeks('1') is not working.

How can I get data from my wp_users table?

THNX!

Comment: Of course it's not working because what is wp_user_weeks?  Did you create that function?  If not, then why do you expect it to exist?   Probably shouldn't be trying to add your own code in if you aren't at all familiar with PHP, you'll likely end up breaking something or creating a vulnerability.  Study PHP and Wordpress development, then come to ask questions.

Comment: Did you add this as a custom field to the wp_users table? That's not part of the official spec: https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_users

Comment: Yes is added the field 'weeks' to the table

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with the following code:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( $user->weeks == 1 ) {
   echo 'something';
}
```

THNX!

Comment: The real problem was you are expecting boolean from function to check condition which is not correct .